# Why can't I ping over IPv6?

Tags: networking, ipv6, ping

I can browse normally, I can create this question for example, apt update works fine, but when I was trying to install firebase using npm, I received a time out (`npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/firebase-admin failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6810:1b22:80`), so I tried to ping to the npm:

```
felipe@nitro:~$ ping -c10 -6 registry.npmjs.org
PING registry.npmjs.org(2606:4700::6810:1f22 (2606:4700::6810:1f22)) 56 data bytes

--- registry.npmjs.org ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 9217ms

felipe@nitro:~$ ping -c10 -4 registry.npmjs.org
PING  (104.16.29.34) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 104.16.29.34 (104.16.29.34): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=13.0 ms
64 bytes from 104.16.29.34 (104.16.29.34): icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=13.3 ms
64 bytes from 104.16.29.34 (104.16.29.34): icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=12.7 ms
64 bytes from 104.16.29.34 (104.16.29.34): icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=13.3 ms
64 bytes from 104.16.29.34 (104.16.29.34): icmp_seq=5 ttl=56 time=12.7 ms
64 bytes from 104.16.29.34 (104.16.29.34): icmp_seq=6 ttl=56 time=13.1 ms
64 bytes from 104.16.29.34 (104.16.29.34): icmp_seq=7 ttl=56 time=12.6 ms
64 bytes from 104.16.29.34 (104.16.29.34): icmp_seq=8 ttl=56 time=13.2 ms
64 bytes from 104.16.29.34 (104.16.29.34): icmp_seq=9 ttl=56 time=13.0 ms
64 bytes from 104.16.29.34 (104.16.29.34): icmp_seq=10 ttl=56 time=13.0 ms

---  ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 12.608/13.006/13.293/0.238 ms
```

I then tried to ping Google:

```
felipe@nitro:~$ ping -c10 www.google.com
PING www.google.com(2800:3f0:4004:80b::2004 (2800:3f0:4004:80b::2004)) 56 data bytes

--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 9217ms

felipe@nitro:~$ ping -c10 -4 www.google.com
PING  (142.250.79.36) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from rio07s04-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.79.36): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=53.4 ms
64 bytes from rio07s04-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.79.36): icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=51.9 ms
64 bytes from rio07s04-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.79.36): icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=53.5 ms
64 bytes from rio07s04-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.79.36): icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=53.1 ms
64 bytes from rio07s04-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.79.36): icmp_seq=5 ttl=56 time=53.2 ms
64 bytes from rio07s04-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.79.36): icmp_seq=6 ttl=56 time=52.8 ms
64 bytes from rio07s04-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.79.36): icmp_seq=7 ttl=56 time=54.1 ms
64 bytes from rio07s04-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.79.36): icmp_seq=8 ttl=56 time=53.1 ms
64 bytes from rio07s04-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.79.36): icmp_seq=9 ttl=56 time=53.3 ms
64 bytes from rio07s04-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.79.36): icmp_seq=10 ttl=56 time=53.1 ms

---  ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9012ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 51.892/53.155/54.130/0.536 ms
```

It seems to me to be something related to IPv6, but I don't know exactly how to check the health of IPv6. I haven't changed anything so far so I don't know what could be wrong.

Comment: You might need to add proxy in npm config. Checkout https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17947

Comment: "I don't know exactly how to check the health of IPv6." In addition to your experiment with `ping`, try `curl google.com`, as-is, and with `-4` and `-6`. If both `ping` and `curl` can't reach Google (or some other test site) over IPv6, Ferrybig's answer is most likely correct.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe the output you received from pinging www.google.com with `ping -c10 -4 www.google.com` is normal and expected because your internet service provider's service plan does not support pinging the Internet Protocol version 6 (IPv6) address family. If this is the case pinging your internet service provider with a command of the form `ping -c2 -6 <URL-of-your-ISP>` will output the following results.

```
ping: URL-of-your-ISP: Address family for hostname not supported
```

For more verbose output you can test your IPv6 connectivity from a web browser by visiting [Test your IPv6](https://test-ipv6.com/). For example, if your IPv6 connectivity does not exist you may get the following IPv6 test output.

> Your DNS server (possibly run by your ISP) appears to have no access to the IPv6 Internet, or is not configured to use it. This may in the future restrict your ability to reach IPv6-only sites.

Answer (score 4):

Your machine has a malfunctioning internet connection.

It is setup with an (probably automatic) IPv6 internet connection, where it knows it has its own global IPv6 address and knows which router to use, but when trying to actually use it, it just times out.

Certain program like ping or node just try to connect to the first resolved IP address. IPv6 is returned because it is preferred by the system. Because the connection is broken, things just timeout.

Programs like web browsers or apt (which uses curl)  actually tries IPv4 within 1 second after IPv6, then picks the fastest of the 2, hiding your internet connection issues

Comment: This, IMHO, is more likely the correct answer. It might also be worth testing what Python does; IIRC, Python will try IPv6, time out after 120s, then try IPv4. As noted, some programs will try IPv4 either concurrently or after a very short delay, which tends to mask non-working IPv6.

Comment: As someone who has done low-level network programming, fallback on failure is pretty trivial to add to a simple client implementation. Whereas implementing "happy eyeballs" requires managing multiple sockets at the same time which comes with a large step-up in complexity.